# How to select multiple non-sequential lines in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there any way to select multiple lines in Vim?

For example I want to select line number 1,4,7,8 etc?

I know that I can use V or v to select lines but they select the continuous lines.

For example when I want to add comments `#` or `//` etc in different lines. I remember that Sublime-text 2 can do it, so I am wondering if Vim can do it too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [multiselect - Create multiple selections and operate on them](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=953) plugin allows just that. It's great for those cases where a selection via `:global` would be impossible or too cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. However, depending on what you are actually trying to 
accomplish, try the below things.

If you're trying to highlight multiple lines so they stand out, 
see `:he matchadd()`

If you're trying to run a command on multiple lines,

```
see :he :g 
and :he :v
```

For any of these, the "match on this line" regex items may be of 
use, `:he /\%l`

Comment: And if you're trying to copy non-sequential lines, use a lower-case register (`"a` for example) for the first line and the uppercase of the register for the rest (`"A`). See `:help quote_alpha`